# What object/function should I use to retrieve a url of my choice?

Tags: javascript, location, javascript-objects

Hello Guys I am getting Started with Javascript and I would like to develop one very simple silly tool that displays the url of any website I chose.

I know that there is the Object called Location, but that one only retrieves my current url.

Check this simple example that I got from one tutorial

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Display the entire URL of the current page.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
"Page location is: " + window.location.href;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to do this but for one url of my choice, instead of my current one.
What object/function should I use?

Comment: That code only runs on the page it is on, not sure how you would expect it to run on on other pages

Comment: What do you mean by _one url of my choice_? Then you could replace `window.location.href` by anything you want!

Comment: @epascarello I know it runs on the current page, I just posted it as an example. What I need to know is what is the function that I should use to retrieve a url of my choice. Any help is welcome. Sarcastic criticism is not needed. Thanks

Comment: Where would you get the URL of your choice? Where is the url loaded/referenced from?

Comment: ´@ibrahimmahrir Hey, by url of my choice, is like, for example, fill in a field with an url string and then retrieving the info not on the current page but on the url I fill in. So actually I believe I should need two functions, one to create a kind of a "form" and the other to put the url string to the form and use it to retrieve information about the designated page.

Comment: So create a form and reference the input. Now the issue with JavaScirpt is it can not read data from other sites because of the same origin policy.  So you can load it, but you most likely will be able to read from it. But what you want to learn about is probably Ajax/XMLHttpRequest object.